# Como remover objeto de dentro de uma lista de objetos em c#? List<>

Tags: c#

Bom, estou tentando remover um objeto de dentro de um lista, mas ocorre erro.

```
  public void RemoveAluno(List<Aluno> listadealunos)
    {
        if (listadealunos.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Não é possível excluir aluno.");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Qual aluno deseja remover? ");
            string nomealuno = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (Aluno aluno in listadealunos)

            {  //Aluno = objeto com nome, nota e algumas métodos.

                if (aluno.Nome == nomealuno)
                {
                    listadealunos.Remove(aluno);
                }

            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

EDIT 16:33 : Mudei o foreach (Aluno aluno in listadealunos) para  foreach (Aluno aluno in listadealunos.ToList())
E resolveu o problema. Não sei o que acabei de fazer, mas caso alguém souber e tiver disposto a explicar didaticamente eu agradeço... mas certamente irei pesquisar mais a fundo mais tarde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode modificar uma Collection enquanto interage com ela.
Se você quer remover um item, você pode fazer como o Julio Cesar disse que é usando Linq e colocando a clausula do seu If dentro do Where, ou então criar uma coleção secundaria com os valores a serem removidos e depois percorre-la removendo da lista original. A solução do Julio Cesar é a mais elegante.